# How to use UITableviewcell dragStateDidChange method in the custom tableview cell class

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm using a custom UITableviewCell class, my requirement is to know when the cell is scrolled away from the screen in the custom class itself (do not want to use the cellForRowAtIndexPath method). I'm not sure if dragStateDidChange method is used to serve my purpose. I did not see enough documentation in the developer.apple.com. If dragStateDidChange method is not used for serving my purpose, may I know when this method can be used. This is more of like a research on knowing the UITableviewCell methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The movement of table cells on and off screen is handled through a `UIScrollView`.  I believe what you want to do is monitor the visibleCells property of the table view and react when it changes.

The dragState is relevant when someone is dragging something onto a table view that has been marked to accept drag and drop. (see, for example, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/drag_and_drop/adopting_drag_and_drop_in_a_table_view)